# Microsoft Outlook hiding text after pressing enter

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook, office365

When typing an email, the previous line of text is hidden after pressing enter. Then, the cursor is stuck and can't be moved.

I've checked if it's deleting the text and it's not, since when sending the email to a different email, you receive the hidden text as well. I've scoured the internet for solutions for this and it's not Overtype, line breaks, or formatting issues. It does not occur on other applications, only the Outlook app. I've also tried repairing the application and that did not work.

I am using Outlook as part of Microsoft Office 365. It is the newest version and my computer is running Windows 10.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Are you using the Outlook desktop app or the web app? If you are using the web app, what web browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

FYI - looks like an update bug, folks on Reddit investigating.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/na7h69/outlook_2016_text_in_the_body_is_disappearing/

From above Reddit post, this worked for me:

*Issue solved here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Outlook/comments/na500m/outlook_messages_only_partially_loading/
Run the follow in CMD as admin.
"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13901.20462*

Answer (score 0):

Issue can also be resolved by simply updating MS Office. This can be done on any of the platforms (Word, Excel, Outlook, etc.) by going to the FILE tab, selecting Account (or Office Account) from the options on the left hand side of the window, pull down the Update Options and select Update now. Once the update is complete you should no longer have the issue.